# How to use RFID / NFC using Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

As the title suggest, I want to implement an RFID reader into my blazor app.

Traditionally DotNetCore apps run serverside. But with blazor clientside would it be possible?

Alternatively does blazor support Active X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update:

**Assuming** you're referring to using desktop PC .NET assemblies that work with common RFID and NFC hardware over local communication ports (COM, USB, Bluetooth, etc), then no, it is not possible.

However, in a few years, if browser vendors add support for [proposed JavaScript APIs for NFC and RFID hardware ("Web NFC")](https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/) then you could use the those APIs from your code.

Some RFID hardware vendors (both system-integrators and actual hardware OEMs) provide infrastructure-based readers/scanners (the kind that are permanently mounted on a wall or ceiling) that provide HTTP-based web-services (SOAP, REST, something else, etc) that your Blazor code could also use.

Here's a list:

- Internet/LAN website or PWA using in-browser JavaScript APIs:

  - Direct-attached (including PAN/Bluetooth) RFID+NFC reader hardware:

    - Bluetooth: **Potentially**, [provided you use the Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API), it depends on hardware and browser support. (Also note that Bluetooth LE and "normal" Bluetooth are very different despite sharing the "Bluetooth" brand).
    - USB/COM: **Presently no** [as WebUSB support is disabled in Chromium-based browsers](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-disables-chrome-webusb/) and no other browsers support it.
  - Infrastructure scanners/readers with HTTP-based web-services: **Yes**, provided you can access them using `fetch`/`XMLHTTPRequest`, `EventSource` or `WebSocket`.
- Internet/LAN website or PWA using C# code and .NET libraries from within Blazor (so **not** calling in-browser JavaScript APIs from within Blazor)

  - Direct-attached (including PAN/Bluetooth) RFID+NFC reader hardware: **No** (because OS services/syscalls aren't available in Blazor).
  - Infrastructure scanners/readers with HTTP-based web-services: **Yes**, provided you can access them using `HttpClient`.
- Device App (Mobile or Desktop) using Cordova/PhoneGap or Electron:

  - Direct-attached (including PAN/Bluetooth) RFID+NFC reader hardware: **Potentially**, based on what extra APIs are provided by the Cordova, PhoneGap or Electron environment.
  - Infrastructure scanners/readers with HTTP-based web-services: **Yes**, provided you can access them using `fetch`/`XMLHTTPRequest`, `EventSource` or `WebSocket`.
- Desktop computer with a service process installed on the user's computer that interacts with the web-application  over a localhost-only HTTP listener:

  - **Yes**. See my original answer below.
  - Note that this solution means that the service process could communicate with your web-application directly without the need for a web-browser application.

### Original answer:

In short: No. It is not possible.

While Blazor code does indeed run on the client, it isn't running as native CPU instructions (it's actually running as interpreted or JIT-compiled Web-Assembly code in the browser's JavaScript engine) - which means it's also very tightly sandboxed.

In short: **In Blazor, if there isn't a browser-provided API for interacting with the computer beyond the browser then you simply can't do it**.

For an explanation: .NET code is able to run in Blazor because Blazor [includes a *tiny* version of the .NET runtime engine (e.g. for managed-object garbage collection) as well as shrunken versions of the main .NET base-class-library assemblies which are downloaded on-demand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/26/whats-behind-the-hype-about-blazor/) - so browsers don't actually download your entire 20MB+ sized Blazor app all at once at first.

Blazor essentially ships its own version of `mscorlib.dll`, System.dll`` and other assemblies which stub-out all operations involving platform services that are unavailable in the browser and instead they `throw new PlatformNotSupportedException` - so if you try to use, for example, the filesystem API in .NET (`System.IO.File`, etc) then you'll get an exception/error.

Within *any* Turing Complete programming environment on a PC (like Blazor and WebAssembly) you can do any information processing task you want but any program activity that makes *something happen* in real-life (e.g. IO, making a syscall, controlling a hardware device) has to go through the operating-system via a syscall, .NET syscalls happen internally in the CLR (often seen with `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` methods and P/Invoke (`[DllImport]`) methods) - which aren't made at all by the Blazor CLR - though some APIs are remapped to native JavaScript, e.g. `Console.WriteLine` is mapped to `console.log`.

As for ActiveX - no browser has supported unrestricted, non-sandboxed ActiveX controls for over 15 years. ActiveX is dead. Browsers have also dropped support for Java applets as well.

### Possible workaround:

That said, provided you can install your own programs on the client computer then you can have your web-application (even if it's hosted on a public Internet website) communicate with a client program over a local HTTP server (which includes WebSockets) accessd from a `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` request made by a local browser (no external connections, fortunately). This is how the Dell Computers website's "Find my computer's service-tag" feature works: Dell computers come pre-installed with a small web-server that listens for loopback requests and replies with the service-tag (I think requests do need to be signed so third-party websites can't do the same thing to get the Dell service-tags of their visitors).

1. Write a separate program (e.g. a Windows Service daemon) that:

   1. runs a micro HTTP server that listens on only `127.0.0.1:12345` and performs RFID/NFC actions in response to incoming requests.
   2. Add support for `websocket` requests for bi-directional communication too.
   3. Ensure that all requests are authorized, such as cryptographically signing requests using a server-side private key and your program **must** verify the validity of incoming requests to prevent unauthorized requests.
   4. You should also use a `HTTP` binding exclusively - though I'm unsure of the best way to generate and trust a certificate for `localhost`.
2. Your client-side code would then use `fetch( 'https://localhost:1234/do-stuff-with-rfid' )`. If you're using signed requests and requests are initiated by the client-code (not the web-server code) then you'll need to be more creative with how requests are authenticated.

Comment: All very correct fort the current Blazor Wasm-in-Browser application type. Blazor on Electron and Mobile Blazor bindings are still in very early development but they will let you access the full platform.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The idea of an installable app running Blazor inside Electron makes me die inside. What next... an app written in Python running on IronPython inside Blazor inside an Electron app? Gah!

Comment: I'm not sure all of these projects will flourish but Blazor/C# as a common programming model isn't too bad. Note that .net 5 will have better AOT support, this can run very lean and mean.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Right, but .NET is meant to be portable in the first place - I wonder how much work it would be to have a build of Electron with built-in (native) .NET Core CLR in addition to V8 JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

the answere is partial wrong. NFC with Blazor is possible.
Yes the browser is a sandbox and Blazor lifes in it. So a sandbox in a sandbox. But with the JavaScript APi you can access each Browser API.
Surprise there is a draft for it https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/

Would I do this in browser? never ever. NFC in general is a complicated topic, cause of diffrent standards, format, devicess. I coded it using a library and UWP, within a few hours.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I didn't know about the Web NFC proposal. I'll update my answer now.